# In which context should I use glassfish-embedded-web as dependency in my maven-project

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, grizzly

I am developing a project using grizzly-framework, which is a component integrated by glassfish. The project consists in building an agent, which is getting requests from lot of clients. This agent should  then process the requests by communicating to a cloud-platform and getting information from there. The agent is based on grizzly. Since I do not have experience using glassfish, so I have mainly two questions:

1) I am asking, in which context I should use glassfish-embedded-web in my actual project.

2) Which benefits can I have when using this dependency?

Comment: What is the Glassfish role in your project? You say the agent is based on Grizzly, so why do you need Glassfish?

Comment: I am using this dependency in my pom.xml file <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-websockets</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.22</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: all my dependencies in my pom.xml are depedend on glassfish inclusive grizzly which is dependent on glassfish

Comment: I have also this dependency <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
        <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.22</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: Right, but all of these modules are part of plain Grizzly project, they don't have to have any Glassfish dependencies

Comment: I get the dependencies from https://grizzly.java.net/dependencies.html

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I want to avoid as far as possible glassfish, since I using  java SE. If you have suggestions, I will be very happy

Comment: right, but there is no glassfish dependency in the list you mentioned. May you are confused by Grizzly package "org.glassfish.grizzly", it's doesn't mean Glassfish dependency, it's just because Grizzly is a subproject of Glassfish project, but at the same time it could be used standalone.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I was really confused